Im having problems with translating this script. Can someone please help me?
*I believe this could be the nane of the artist on my Chinese ink and watercolorpainting. Someone said that it may be translated as "Qi Baishi" but I'm not sure.

You are in possession of an original?

I think so. Recently found two paintings by this artist. I think ithey might be much earlier than those that usually come up for auction


白石 = white stone

山人(mountain man) = hermit

白石山人 - Bai Shi Shan Ren


It is the famous 齊白石s (Qi Baishi) another pen name

Thank you Tang!

"白石山人" - alias of the famous artist 齐白石 -

齐白石（1864年1月1日—1957年9月16日），原名齐纯芝，字渭清，祖父取号兰亭，老师取名璜，字濒生，别号寄萍老人、白石山人，湖南湘潭人，近代中国"国画"画家。后人常将“山人”二字略去，故后常号“白石”。齐白石也和张大千并称“南张北齐”。

